# Setting variables in class hierarchy

Tags: java, class, variables, inheritance, hierarchy

I'm writing a program to find the volume and surface areas of shapes based on class hierarchies for school. I'm trying to get a method in the main class to set the variables in an abstract class, but it isn't working.

Here's the main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShapeDriver{

  public double cubeSide;

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for cube, 2 for rectangular prism, 3 for cylinder, 4 for cone, or 5 for sphere.");
    int shapeNum = input.nextInt();

    if(shapeNum == 1){
      ShapeDriver shDriver = new ShapeDriver();
      PrismSet prism = new PrismSet();
      System.out.println("Enter the length of a side of the cube.");
      shDriver.cubeSide = input.nextDouble();
      prism.setCubeLength();

      Cube cu = new Cube();
      System.out.println("Surface area: " + cu.surfaceArea());
      System.out.println("Volume: " + cu.volume());
    }

  }

}
```

Here's the abstract class with the variables prismWidth and prismHeight that I want to change:

```
public abstract class Prisms implements ShapeFunctions{

  public double prismWidth;
  public double prismHeight;
  public double prismDepth;

  public double findFrontBackFaceArea(double prismHeight, double prismWidth){
    double prismFrontBackFaceArea = prismHeight * prismWidth * 2;
    return prismFrontBackFaceArea;
  }

  public double findRightLeftFaceArea(double prismHeight, double prismDepth){
    double prismRightLeftFaceArea = prismHeight * prismWidth * 2;
    return prismRightLeftFaceArea;
  }

  public double findTopBottomFaceArea(double prismWidth, double prismDepth){
    double prismTopBottomFaceArea = prismWidth * prismDepth * 2;
    return prismTopBottomFaceArea;
  }

}
```

And here's the class I wrote to try to access the variables in the abstract class:

```
public class PrismSet extends Prisms{

  public double surfaceAreaHolder;
  public double volumeHolder;

  public void setCubeLength(){
    ShapeDriver sDriver = new ShapeDriver();
    super.prismHeight = sDriver.cubeSide;
    super.prismWidth = sDriver.cubeSide;
  }

  public double surfaceArea(){
    return surfaceAreaHolder;
  }

  public double volume(){
    return volumeHolder;
  }


}
```

When I enter a number as a value for cubeSide, it returns 0.0 for both the surface area and volume. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here's the Cube class:

```
public class Cube extends Prisms implements ShapeFunctions{

  public double surfaceArea(){
    double cubeSurfaceArea = super.findFrontBackFaceArea(super.prismHeight, super.prismWidth) * 3;
    return cubeSurfaceArea;
  }

  public double volume(){
    double cubeVolume = Math.pow(super.prismWidth, 3);
    return cubeVolume;
  }

 }
```

Comment: you are initializing new objects everywhere. How does your Cube class look?

Comment: you are doing this a bit wrong. Once you find out that it's cube in if(shapeNum == 1), why do you make a PrismSet object. It's much simpler to define a Cube object and stick with it.

Comment: I have to set the variables in the Prisms class for the Cube class to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to modify this method in PrismSet

```
public void setCubeLength(ShapeDriver sDriver){
 super.prismHeight = sDriver.cubeSide;
 super.prismWidth = sDriver.cubeSide;
}
```

and pass it the `shDriver`

---

Also change ShapeDriver class to:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for cube, 2 for rectangular prism, 3 for cylinder, 4 for cone, or 5 for sphere.");
    int shapeNum = input.nextInt();

    if(shapeNum == 1){
      ShapeDriver shDriver = new ShapeDriver();
      Cube cube = new Cube();
      System.out.println("Enter the length of a side of the cube.");
      shDriver.cubeSide = input.nextDouble();
      cube.setCubeLength(shDriver); // change this also

      System.out.println("Surface area: " + cu.surfaceArea());
      System.out.println("Volume: " + cu.volume());
    }

  }
```

---

Ok, so, I thought that you wanted your Cube to extend PrismSet, or else, I'm not sure what you want to achieve.
I managed to get this working with this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShapeDriver {

    public double cubeSide;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for cube, 2 for rectangular prism, 3 for cylinder, 4 for cone, or 5 for sphere.");
        int shapeNum = input.nextInt();

        if (shapeNum == 1) {
            ShapeDriver shDriver = new ShapeDriver();
            Cube cube = new Cube();
            System.out.println("Enter the length of a side of the cube.");
            shDriver.cubeSide = input.nextDouble();
            cube.setCubeLength(shDriver);

            System.out.println("Surface area: " + cube.surfaceArea());
            System.out.println("Volume: " + cube.volume());
        }
    }
}
```

Prisms:

```
public abstract class Prisms implements ShapeFunctions {

    public double prismWidth;
    public double prismHeight;
    public double prismDepth;

    public double findFrontBackFaceArea(double prismHeight, double prismWidth) {
        double prismFrontBackFaceArea = prismHeight * prismWidth * 2;
        return prismFrontBackFaceArea;
    }

    public double findRightLeftFaceArea(double prismHeight, double prismDepth) {
        double prismRightLeftFaceArea = prismHeight * prismWidth * 2;
        return prismRightLeftFaceArea;
    }

    public double findTopBottomFaceArea(double prismWidth, double prismDepth) {
        double prismTopBottomFaceArea = prismWidth * prismDepth * 2;
        return prismTopBottomFaceArea;
    }

}
```

PrismSet

```
public class PrismSet extends Prisms {

    public double surfaceAreaHolder;
    public double volumeHolder;

    public void setCubeLength(ShapeDriver sDriver) {
        super.prismHeight = sDriver.cubeSide;
        super.prismWidth = sDriver.cubeSide;
    }

    public double surfaceArea() {
        return surfaceAreaHolder;
    }

    public double volume() {
        return volumeHolder;
    }

}
```

Cube

```
public class Cube extends PrismSet implements ShapeFunctions {

    public double surfaceArea() {
        double cubeSurfaceArea = super.findFrontBackFaceArea(super.prismHeight, super.prismWidth) * 3;
        return cubeSurfaceArea;
    }

    public double volume() {
        double cubeVolume = Math.pow(super.prismWidth, 3);
        return cubeVolume;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to Java. What do you mean by pass it the shDriver?

Comment: Wouldn't putting sDriver in the arguments take away it's constructor, meaning it doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: you already intialized that object. Why initialize it once more?

Comment: shDriver.cubeSide = input.nextDouble(); means that that ShapeDriver got that input.

Then, in setCubeLength you initialize a new ShapeDrive, which has nothing to do with shDriver. So prismHeight and width are initialzed (strangely, I might add) to 0...

Comment: I replaced every object with the shDriver , but everything is still 0. Should I still have 2 objects?

Comment: Thanks! That worked. The thing that made it work was making Cube extend PrismSet.